# Is there an RUnit checkException for warning()?

Tags: unit-testing, r

checkException will validate if meeting a stop() call, but not a warning() call. 
Is there a workaround or hack to check for warnings? (and make them silent during testing)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can simply use

```
> options(warn=2)
```

in the setup code to turn warnings into errors?

See `help(options)` for the paragraph on this option.

Comment: yes that will do the trick... but I guess I'll need to run tests that are supposed make warnings twice: once with options(warn=2) while checking that they make an error, and once with options(warn=1) while checking that they do not.
Thanks!